# Add HTML markup to a new paragraph text field

Tags: 8

I'm creating a new paragraph item within a hook_node_presave() function.

The paragraph item is fairly simple, just a title and body text written into a text field with full html text editing. When I attempt to html elements within the body text, I'm unable to get the content to render the HTML tags.

Is there a way to do this using a render array, or another technique?

This is my initial attempt to build the paragraph, putting my html tags directly into the field that contains the body content.

```php
$summary_paragraph = Paragraph::create([
  'type' => 'paragraph_text', //this is the paragraph type
  'field_title' => 'Title text',
  'field_content' => '<p>Sentence one.</p><p>Sentence two</p>.',
]);
```

The title appears correctly and *field_content* prints the tags along with the text.

I also tried with a render array.

```php
$content_text = [
  '#type' => 'processed_text',
  '#text' => '<p>Paragraph one.</p><p>Paragraph two.</p>',
  '#format' => 'full_html',
];
      
$summary_paragraph = Paragraph::create([
  'type' => 'paragraph_text', //this is the paragraph type
  'field_title' => 'Title text',
  'field_content' => $content_text,
]);
```

In this case, only the title was printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store a formatted text field you need a field array with two properties `value` and `format`:

```
$summary_paragraph = Paragraph::create([
  // ...
  'field_content' => [
    'value' => '<p>Paragraph one.</p><p>Paragraph two.</p>',
    'format' => 'full_html',
  ],
]);
```

Comment: Thank you @4k4, that worked perfectly.